# Map unconventional JSON to pojo with CXF JAX-RS client

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I've built several JAX-RS based REST services using CXF.  I've always had the ability to define my own schema, so I never had any issues mapping the response to a pojo.

I'm now looking at writing some client code that connects to a foreign service which returns JSON, but it's "unconventional" from my POV.

The response I get looks something like this:

```
{
    "addOnOffers": [
        {
            "offer": {
                "offerId": 4000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If "addOnOffers" is my root element, the fact that the value is a list, and not a single element, confuses me.  I don't understand how to map that to a pojo.

**Update**:

It's clear to me that this will require a custom MessageBodyReader implementation, I'm just not sure what facilities CXF provides out of the box to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this on the cxf-users mailing list, and Andy McCright  gave me a useful response.

He pointed me to the following example class that does something like what I need: https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-conference/blob/master/microservice-vote/src/main/java/io/microprofile/showcase/vote/api/AttendeeProvider.java .